# Truncate text with CSS but add text instead of ellipsis

Tags: css, truncate, truncation

I want to truncate a single line of text based on responsive width, and add "and more" to the end without breaking in the middle of a word. I've pieced together a sort-of-working example, but I can't get it to work with center-aligned text.

https://jsfiddle.net/p02147zd/2/

When a box doesn't need the "and more" on the end, it is misaligned because it still has that padding-right that is required to leave room for that text. It looks fine if I left-align the text, but I need it to be centered. Any ideas?

```
.foo {
  padding-right: 58px; /* Always have room for "and more" */
  height: 1.1em; /* Only allow one line of text */
  overflow: hidden; /* Hide all the text below that line */
  background-color: yellow;
}
.foo > span {
  display: inline-block; /* These have to be inline block to wrap correctly */
  position: relative; /* Give "and more" an anchor point so it's positioned after the element */
  background-color: yellow; /* Cover "and more" of the previous element with the same background color */
  white-space: pre; /* Make sure the only point where wrapping is allowed is before a comma */
}
.foo > span:after {
  position: absolute; /* Take "and more" out of the flow, so the next item will cover it */
  content: 'and more'; /* Each span has an "and more" */
  margin-left:2px;
}
.foo > span:last-child:after {
  content: ""; /* Except for the last one */
}
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, I don't know any solution in CSS,

but if you can use JavaScript, this example code can help:

https://jsfiddle.net/orovan/89db4yw2/15/

```js
$(function(){
  and_more();
  $(window).resize(function(){
    and_more();
  });
});

function and_more(){
  $('.and-more').remove();
  $('.foo').removeClass('has-more');
  $('.foo').each(function(){
    $t = $(this);
    $total_width = $t.width();
    $width = 0;
    $done = false;
    $t.find('span').each(function(){
      $width = $width + $(this).width();
      if($width > $total_width && $done == false){
        $(this).before('<span class="and-more">and more</span>');
        $t.addClass('has-more');
        $done = true;
      }
    });
  });
}
```

```css
.foo {
  padding: 0 30px;
  height: 1.1em; /* Only allow one line of text */
  overflow: hidden; /* Hide all the text below that line */
  background-color: yellow;
}
.foo > span {
  display: inline-block; /* These have to be inline block to wrap correctly */
  position: relative; /* Give "and more" an anchor point so it's positioned after the element */
  background-color: pink; /* Cover "and more" of the previous element with the same background color */
  white-space: pre; /* Make sure the only point where wrapping is allowed is before a comma */
}

.foo i {
  margin:2px;
  font-style:normal;
  position:relative;
}
.foo i:after {
  content:','
}
.foo > span:last-child i:after {
  content:'';
}

.wrap {
 padding:10px;
 background:yellow;
  position:relative;
  margin:10px;
  width:25%;
  text-align:center;
}

.grid {
  display:flex;
  flex-flow:wrap;
}

.foo.has-more{
  padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="grid">


<div class="wrap">

  <div class="foo">
    <!-- These *must not* have white space between them, or it will collapse to a space before the comma, and the ellipsis will become visible -->
    <span><i>design</i></span><span><i>account</i></span><span><i>web design</i></span><span><i>branding</i></span>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="wrap">

  <div class="foo">
    <!-- These *must not* have white space between them, or it will collapse to a space before the comma, and the ellipsis will become visible -->
    <span><i>design</i></span><span><i>animation</i></span>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="wrap">

  <div class="foo">
    <!-- These *must not* have white space between them, or it will collapse to a space before the comma, and the ellipsis will become visible -->
    <span><i>cinematography</i></span><span><i>account management</i></span><span><i>web design</i></span><span><i>branding</i></span>
  </div>
</div>
</div>


That middle box should be centered because it doesn't have the "and more" but it still has the padding to account for it.


<p>
(The pink bg would normally be yellow to match the box bg. Just wanted to highlight the different elements for testing.)
</p>
```

Comment: I used your JS to just add/remove the .has-more class, and then used CSS to style from there. That solved the problem and required a little less JS. I'll come back to mark this correct tomorrow, just in case someone comes in with a CSS-only solution. Thank you!

Comment: The CSS solution would also interest me. Did you find any?

Comment: No I didn't. Thank you for reminding to mark this correct, though!